# PhpMyAdmin login error on Synology NAS

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, synology

First of all. I ran a mysql server before of a dell laptop using Ubuntu. Now I have a Synology NAS that is on 24/7. I think it is beter to run my mysql server there. So I installed it and everything went well till I made a second account (I logged in with my root and created a new phpmyadmin user account). I tried to log in and it gave this message.

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'douwedevries'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Now I have my port 3306 (TCP) opened to my NAS. But if I look at the message it says 'localhost', so no portforwarding.

I don't know how to solve this or what to do. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the user, what host value did you use? Since phpMyAdmin is using the MySQL socket connection, the user you've created needs to say localhost (that's indicated by the 'localhost', instead of doing it over TCP/IP networking which would show 127.0.0.1 or a full hostname/IP address). MySQL treats 127.0.0.1 or '%' as being different from localhost. You'll need to edit the user to change the host to 'Local' (or 'localhost', depending on which version you have) as the wildcard % only applies to TCP/IP connections, not socket connections.

Since phpMyAdmin is running locally on your NAS, you don't need to expose port 3306 to the network, all you need is to be able to get to the web page (typically port 80) from the rest of your network. You'd need port 3306 if you were connecting directly to MySQL, but that's not needed here.